# How to move a Tkinter button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am new to Python and Tkinter and I am needing to move a button.

I have been using `button1.pack()` to place the button.

I am not able to move the button from its original position at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Look at .grid() or .place()

Comment: By "move", do you mean "put it somewhere else", or "have it move across the screen in an animated fashion"?

Comment: Provide more information about your code and what you are trying exactly to achieve, because it is difficult to guess exactly your intentions.

Comment: I mean to move the button to a new position. Not making it animated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolute position

```
button1.place(x=some_value, y=some_value)
```

or relative position

```
button1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=some_value, pady=some_value)
```

padx, pady - paddings

Answer (score 1):

`button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)`

But this cannot be used together with pack(), you need to stick to either one.

And this only orders objects relatively, so if you have only one object and you set the row and column to 40 and 50, respectively, the object will still be on the top left corner.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I have to only use grid()? Can I use pack in other sections?

Comment: You can use them in the same script, but not in the same tkinter master window.

Also, this website gives you an overview with nice examples: http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php

Answer (score 0):

animated movement:

```
import time, tkinter

X,Y=,0,0

for i in range(pixelsToMove):
   button.place(x=X,y=Y)
   X=X+1
   Y=Y+1
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

it will move to the bottom right corner slowly here is how to adjust it:

to move to the right ONLY at a set Y then at the `y=Y` part do `y=set_y` and for x do the same thing to move left change `X=X+1` do `X=X-1` and at `X,Y = 0,0` do `X,Y = start_x,0` same for y.